# How to render dynamic fields on List Component of React-admin

Tags: react-admin

I am trying to render dynamically generated fields on the List view of React-admin. Datagrid works fine as long as we pass every field to it hardcoded, but I want to display fields(TextField, DateField etc ...) dynamically based on the type of each field.

For that, I have created a component called `<RenderType/>` which takes as prop the object with the fields of each row and dynamically returns React-admin components (TextField, DateField ) but it doesn't display in different columns but it put all the results on one column.

```
import React from 'react';
import { List, Datagrid, TextField, EditButton } from 'react-admin';

export const PostList = (props) => (
    <List {...props}>
        <Datagrid>
             <RenderType>
            //In this component, I pass the object of the fields 
            //and iterate through them and dynamically
            //return fields based on the field type
            //but I get all fields displayed in one column

        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making use of MUI's Datagrid component rather then going with react-admin's in this instance.

This is their documentation:
https://mui.com/components/data-grid/

There is an implementation of MUI Datagrid for react admin in npm:
https://github.com/marmelab/ra-datagrid

Basically used something like this:

DATA:

```json
[{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}, {"a": 4, "b": 5, "c": 6}, {"a": 7, "b": 8, "c": 9}...]
```

CODE:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Datagrid } from "ra-datagrid"
import {List} from 'react-admin';

const DynamicGridFields = (props) => {
    // Had an odd issue with this triggering and props not being populated yet
    if(props === undefined || props.data === undefined || Object.values(props.data).length == 0)
        return ""; // Blocking if no data

    const columns = [];
    const data = Object.values(props.data);
    const columnList = Object.keys(data[0]);
    for(let index in columnList){
        const column = columnList[index];
        columns.push({
            field: column,
            headerName: column,
            width: 180,
            type: column == "id" ? "string" : "number" // Could do some type checking 
        })
    }
    return <Datagrid columns={columns} rows={data}/>;
};

const MyList = props => {
    return (
        <List {...props}>
            <DynamicGridFields {...props}/>
        </List>
    )
};

export default MyList;
```